# Dynamically create a ListItem comprised of N ListItemTexts

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, listitem

react beginner here after not being able to find any helpful leads while googling.

Given a list of data, in which each data describes what a `ListItem` should contain, how can I dynamically create and return a List of ListItems? Each of the `ListItem` is different (e.g. some have buttons, some dont)

```
const listData = [
        {
            "isClickable":true,
            "horizontalComponents":[
                {
                    "type": "image",
                    "data": {
                        "url": "http://tiny.co/foobar123"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "componentData": {
                        "content": "This is a descriptive text. To view more please click the button on the right."
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "componentData": {
                        "buttonString": "View More"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    listData.forEach(itemData => {
        var columns: typeof ListItemText[] = [];
        itemData.horizontalComponents.forEach(component => {
            if (component.type == "text") {
                columns.push(
                    <ListItemText primary={`Line item foo`} />
                )
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: You will have to map your array to ListItems if you can share the code you have tried we can help :)

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan Good point! I've updated the question with the code I've been trying to get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React components accepts array as children, so you may opt to use `map` to return an array of `ListItem`

```js
const listData = [
  {
    "isClickable": true,
    "horizontalComponents": [
      {
        "type": "image",
        "data": {
          "url": "http://tiny.co/foobar123"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "componentData": {
          "content": "This is a descriptive text. To view more please click the button on the right."
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "button",
        "componentData": {
          "buttonString": "View More"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

function App() {
  return (
    <List>
      {listData.map((listitem, index) => (
        <ListItem key={index}>
          {listitem.horizontalComponents.map((component, index) => {
            if (component.type === "text") {
              return (
                <ListItemText key={index}>{component.componentData.content}</ListItemText>
              );
            } else if (component.type === "button") {
              return <Button key={index} variant="contained">{component.componentData.buttonString}</Button>;
            }
          })}
        </ListItem>
      ))}
    </List>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>

  <script type="text/babel">
    const { List, ListItem, ListItemText, Button } = MaterialUI;
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just for anyone else stumbling upon this post in the future -- this answer has helped become the guideline, with some minor changes in mapping the `horizontalComponent`s. (I was also using typescript) 

Because `horizontalComponent`is a union of three different types, I did a bit of a hack by making it look uniformly like the follows:
`"componentData": {
                        "textContent" : null,
                        "url": "",
                        "buttonString": "View More"
                    }
`
There is likely a better solution but am running out of chars